# Is it possible for decision trees to increase entropy of a dataset

Tags: cart, entropy

Is it possible for decision trees to split a set of data into subsets where the sum of the entropies (weighted respectively) of each subset will be greater than the original entropy of the set?

I know its a bit contrived, but can there be a scenario where I would need to worry about negative information gain?

Or will this not be a problem and all I have to do is plug and chug and only minimize entropy after, without worrying about its relationship to entropy before?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289589/can-the-value-of-information-gain-be-negative

duplicate has been found